# Does a set of $n$ orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ forms an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, orthogonality

Given set $S$ of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , for example :
$$
S =
\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} \\
    a_{12} \\
    \vdots \\
    a_{1n} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
,
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{21} \\
    a_{22} \\
    \vdots \\
    a_{2n} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
, \cdots ,
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{n1} \\
    a_{n2} \\
    \vdots \\
    a_{nn} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
 \right\}
$$

and we have to show whether $S$ forms an orthogonal basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , is it enough to prove that $S$ is orthogonal or do I also need anything for a complete proof?

Comment: Orthogonality ensure they aren't linearly dependent so if you can verify they're all orthogonal to each other they'll form an orthogonal basis.

Comment: If your definition of orthogonality allows for vectors to be orthogonal to the zero-vector, then you have to avoid the zero-vector in your set of $n$ vectors.

Comment: This is a good not difficult exercise that you should do yourself. It’s a homework problem that I assign in my undergraduate differential geometry class.